# McAfee Site Advisor indicates that this site is risky to visit?

Tags: discussion

Are you aware that McAfee Site Advisor is indicating that www.askubuntu.com is a risky site to visit?

I'm wondering what they saw that caused this risk rating.

Also, it might have implications into users getting to this site seeing this warning and getting scared off.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have requested they review their decision and I'll poke people further up the SE chain to try and get a proper answer on why they've ranked us so poorly (I can't see it on the [site report](http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/www.askubuntu.com)).

Comment: I don't think there is an actual problem issue though. Both [Google](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=askubuntu.com) and [Symantec](https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=askubuntu.com) think we're good boys and girls. I suspect somebody may have maliciously filed a report against the site on SiteAdvisor but that is speculation. It could be that some of the spam that occasionally rocks up here (and lasts for a few minutes before it's deleted) has been spotted.

Comment: Wat.. trusting McAfee are we? O_o

Comment: There is probably Mrs. Bill Gates touch on it.

Comment: Just [uninstall it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKgf5PaBzyg). [nsfw]

Comment: FWIW, Cisco Ironport and Palo Alto don't have any problems with askubuntu sites....

Comment: @cambraca It will probably cause newbies to think Ubuntu is malware.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Now it is ok

It seems that mcafee re checked website due to user feedbacks and now it displays no risk to visit . Thanks for pointing it out and send reviews to correct it :)

Answer (score 13):

Fear not, friends. We brought out the big guns:

https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/355706390016294912

Comment: He forgot the `@McAfee` part...

Answer (score 5):

I suggest everyone that can (if you are willing to create a user) to request a review saying that the "Red" rating is wrong, And also comment that the site is "No safety issues" at:

http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/www.askubuntu.com

It seems that the site might be ran by user submissions, possibly one user filed a false report - maybe the only report...

But If that is the case It seems they have not reviewed the report properly, and certainly have not documented the reasons for the "Red" rating.

So If you use the site and know it is safe submit a report.

Answer (score -4):

Still the Mcafee supports running only on Mac and Windows.
The site advisor is compatible to run on IE and Mozilla.
On chrome the plugin is not supported officially.

Comment: I almost +1ed this answer for being hilarious.