# Login flow has bad link

Tags: bug, login

Repro steps:

1. Open incognito window / clear cookies
2. [McAfee Site Advisor indicates that this site is risky to visit?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7016/mcafee-site-advisor-indicates-that-this-site-is-risky-to-visit)
3. Press upvote button
4. In login dialog, click "sign up using google"

Result:
404 page http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/authenticate?returnurl=%2Fquestions%2F7016%2Fmcafee-site-advisor-indicates-that-this-site-is-risky-to-visit

Desired result:
A signup page.

Environment:
Current Chrome (27.0.1453.116) on OS X 10.8.4.  Network connection very normal.

Comment: Updated with deets about my system.  Nothing strange here.  Repros on firefox too.

Comment: I can confirm this bug. Happens on plain Ubuntu as well. I am running my own DNS server, VPN to a VPS or even plain commercial ISP at home. Notice that this happens **only on meta**, not on main.

Comment: Oh, so happens with any question on meta?

Comment: @Mateo Yes, any question on meta.

Comment: I can confirm this bug on Windows as well using both Firefox and Chrome. Moreover, "Sign up using Facebook" also returns 404 Error Page. However, "Sign up using Stack Exchange" seems to work well.

Comment: Same here... Just tried it and got the same 404 error. In chrome aswell as in firefox.